# TFDQuery - How to default calculated fields in the dataset to ReadOnly=False

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, firedac

I'm using the FireDAC TFDQuery component to run a SQL `SELECT` statement against a SQL Server database. The SQL statement contains a few 'calculated' column expressions using SQL functions such as `CONVERT` and `CAST`.

In the resulting dataset, these calculated `TField` objects are always set to `ReadOnly=True`. I want to populate these calculated fields in code after the dataset has been returned.

I know I can do this by changing the ReadOnly property of each field :

```
Dataset.FieldByName('MyCalcField').ReadOnly := False;
```

But is there a setting/option within the query components that I can use to force the fields created to always default to `ReadOnly=False`?

Comment: The use of CONVERT and CAST causes the database itself to make those fields read-only, so it won't make any difference if you try to set `ReadOnly` to false - you still won't be able to modify the contents. Without seeing your table schema and the SQL you're using, it's pretty difficult to suggest a way to work around the issue. Typically, the calculations for a calculated field are done at runtime in the `OnCalcFields` event handler, and there is no underlying column in the table itself.

Comment: @KenWhite Setting `TField.ReadOnly := False` on the calculated columns does work - that is my current workaround.  I'm looking for a setting that forces calculated fields to be editable by default.

Comment: A workaround would be to return the SQL data 'as is' and use (Internal)CalcFields in your dataset...